# jQuery cloned element is only appending the cloned item once inside of a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, clone

I am attempting to clone a set of text based on the numerical input of a number field. It seems that the code I've got is only appending the item one time into the `.wrap` element. Is there a limitation with `.clone()` or something else that I'm overlooking that would only append the item once?

**What I Expect to Happen:**
What I expect to happen in the code below is, the `.duplicate` value is updated (let's say to 3), the `.target` element is cloned, then the `.wrap` element is emptied, and the loop runs and appends 3 clones stored in `$clone`. The final `.wrap` element should contain 3 `<h2>Target</h2>` elements.

**What is Happening:**
The above appears to happen, but in the end only 1 `<h2>Target</h2>` elements are appended onto the `.wrap` element.

**Code:**

```js
$( 'body' ).change( '.duplicate', function() {
 
  var count  = $( '.duplicate' ).val(),
      $clone = $( '.target' ).clone(),
      i      = 1;

  $( '.wrap' ).html( '' );

  while ( i <= count ) {

    $( '.wrap' ).append( $clone );

    i++;

  }

} );
```

```css
.duplicate {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" class="duplicate" value="1" min="1" max="5">

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="target">
    <h2>Target</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a new clone each iteration otherwise you are simply moving the original one around each time

Also once you have more than one of that class you only want to clone one of them

```
 $clone = $( '.target' ).first().clone()

 while ( i <= count ) {
     $( '.wrap' ).append( $clone.clone() );
```

Comment: So simple...thank you, your explanation clarifies things. Not sure why I didn't realize that it was only cloning the element one time, and just moving the element around.

Comment: Right `append() `won't make a copy so if it is already in the dom it will just get appended to a new location which in your case is probably the same location and simply replacing itself